# Emacs key inserting problem

Tags: keyboard, emacs

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and since then I started to have a weird problem with my Emacs.

When I type the <kbd>°</kbd> character (which maps to `dead_abovering` on my keyboard) it inserts the sequence `Ä°` (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>°</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> is incidentally how you get the letter `­Ä` on my keyboard).

When I run Emacs under `emacs --no-init` the problem persists, but when I run `emacs -nw` it goes away. And I haven't found any other application that demonstrates this odd behavior, so it seams to be only a problem with my graphical implementation of Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a bug in Emacs. It doesn't recognize the new standard in declaring a locale. See (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeadKeys, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/575084)

I was using the solution presented in the first link by adding `(require 'iso-transl)` to my `.emacs`. It left me the weird <kbd>°</kbd> → `Ä°` for reasons I don't know.

I fixed this by aliasing

```
alias emacs='env XMODIFIERS="" LC_ALL=is_IS.UTF-8 emacs'
```

and by changing the line

```
Exec=emacs %F
```

in `/usr/local/share/applications/emacs.desctop` to

```
Exec=env XMODIFIERS="" LC_ALL=is_IS.UTF-8 emacs %F
```